# Function to find string patterns in file not working?

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I'm trying to write a function that will check if the spooled file contains any error text. The file writes to the expected directory. However, this directory is meant to act as a filter and remove files with error text OR move the file that is clear of any error text.

I keep getting the error:

**grep: ERROR: No such file or directory**

Here is the function in question:

```
exec_error_filter()
{
cd $spoolFilterDir

grep --include "*.csv" "ERROR" -e^SELECT -e^TNS -e^SP2 -e^ORA ${spoolFilterDir}/${report}

if [[ $greprc -eq 0 ]] ; then 
    echo "Erroneous data spooled to .csv report. Removing report."
#   rm *.csv

else
    echo "FOS report successfully generated."

    if [[ $report = "*DailyFOSReport.csv" ]] ; then
        mv "*DailyFOSReport.csv" $daily
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "Daily report moved to daily folder."
        echo "--------------------------------"
    fi

    if [[ $report = "*DailyFOSReport.csv" ]] ; then
        mv "*WeeklyFOSReport.csv" $weekly
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "Weekly report moved to weekly folder."
        echo "--------------------------------"
    fi

    if [[ $report = "*DailyFOSReport.csv" ]] ; then
        mv "*SemiAnnualFOSReport.csv" $monthly
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "Semiannual report moved to semiannual folder."
        echo "--------------------------------"
    fi
fi
}
```

Comment: `grep --include "*.csv" "ERROR"` - what part of the line is the filename? What is the `ERROR` doing there as an argument.

Comment: i'm just checking the csv file. "ERROR" is to check the file for the word "ERROR". Sorry, I'm a noob. By the way you asked I'm assuming my syntax is fubar'd?

Comment: Then start with something simpler. Then what is the whole line `grep --include "*.csv" "ERROR" -e^SELECT -e^TNS -e^SP2 -e^ORA ${spoolFilterDir}/${report}` doing there? Why `--include "*.csv"` if you are not using recursive `-r`? And why the `-e^SELECT -e^TNS -e^SP2 -e^ORA`? If you want to find out if the file has the word `ERROR` in it, just do `if grep -q "ERROR" file ; then .....`

Comment: The issue is if there's a sqlplus issue/error or any error from what I've seen, it will spool the error message to the file. This file is going to mv to a target folder that I do not have full permissions on. I'm trying to only send them working reports, otherwise, erroneous reports will be removed and the error message printed to an error log.

EDIT: Sorry this is just a function out of the entire code. I'm writing results from a sqlplus SELECT query in an earlier function.

Comment: @ChrisTran: it looks like you are trying to do several things (include several CSVs, provide several regexes with `-e`, search in a specific file `{$report}`) in one line that do not quite add up. If you need to grep for several regexes, make sure to put an `-e` in front of all of them.